# Write $5 log_4(x) − log_\frac{1}{4}(y) + 4$ as a single logarithm

Tags: logarithms

$5\log_4(x) − \log_\frac{1}{4}(y) + 4$

The $4$ and $1/4$ are bases. I don't know how to simplify this if the bases are different.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Hint: $\log_{b} x = -\log_{1/b} x$.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the base:
\begin{equation}
\log_{\frac{1}{4}}y=\frac{\log_{4}y}{\log_{4}\frac{1}{4}}=-\log_{4}y
\end{equation}

Now 
\begin{equation}
5\log_4(x) − \log_\frac{1}{4}(y) + 4=5\log_4(x)+\log_4(y)+4=5\log_4(x)+\log_4(y)+4=\\ 5\log_4(x)+\log_4(y)+\log_4(4^4)=\log_4 (4^4x^5y)
\end{equation}

Comment: You went from $-\log_{\frac{1}{4}} (y)$ to $-\log_4 (x)$

Comment: @2012ssohn Thanks...it should be correct now